# How do I edit my Fitocracy profile?

Tags: profile, fitocracy

Today I signed up for an account on [Fitocracy](http://www.fitocracy.com), which is pretty much a social network for tracking (and I guess sharing, if you're into that) your workouts and other fitness achievements. Setting up the account was pretty painless, but now I would like to replace the default profile text under **About me**. I can't find any way to edit this information. I also don't see how to edit my profile picture. I'm ok with the picture for now, but I would sure like to know how to change it in if I want a new one in the future!

I did sign up using my Facebook account, so I wondered if perhaps I might need to edit this information from within Facebook. However, I don't see any way of doing so.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The page is `http://www.fitocracy.com/general-settings/`. You can get there by clicking your profile image thumbnail in the upper right of the page and then clicking **Settings**.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I *finally* found it. If you click on your avatar icon in the toolbar (upper right), it brings up a menu which includes, among other things, a link to edit your profile settings.

Comment: srsly...you beat me by 10 seconds